# Select preferred address if exists otherwise select 'work' address

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

```
PeopleAffiliation: Affiliationid, peopleid, addressid
Addresses: addressid, addresstypeid, address, city, state, zip, preferredaddress (bit)
AddressTypes: addresstypeid, addresstypeconst
```

I need to select all the peopleaffiliation addresses where the address is the preferredaddress but if there's no preferred address then i have to show the address where addresstypeconst = 'Work'

I can't figure out how to do this.  Does anyone know how i can accomplish this?

Below is a sample of what i'm trying to accomplish:

#### Affiliationid, peopleid, addressid

```
    1           1          1
    2           1          2
    3           2          3
    4           2          4
```

#### addressid, addresstypeid, ..., preferredaddress (bit)

```
   1          3                 1  
   2          5                 0
   3          1                 0
   4          5                 0
```

#### addresstypeid, addresstypeconst

```
 1                  Home
 2                  mail
 3                  shipping
 5                  Work
```

### Desired Result

#### Affiliationid, peopleid, addressid

```
    1             1         1
    4             2         4    (showing work address as user doesn't have a preferred one)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   peopleaffiliation pa 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses addr 
                    ON pa.addressid = addr.addressid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN addresstypes addtyp 
                    ON addtyp.addresstypeid = addr.addresstypeid 
WHERE  (addr.preferredaddress = 1 )
        OR( COALESCE(addr.preferredaddress, 0) = 0 
           AND addtyp.addresstypeconst = 'Work' )
```